# most elegant way of escaping $ in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a base String `"abc def"`, I am trying to replace my base string with `"abc$ def$"` using `replaceFirst()`, which is running into errors as `$` is not escaped.

I tried doing it with Pattern and Matcher APIs, as given below,

```
newValue = "abc$ def$";

if(newValue.contains("$")){
    Pattern specialCharacters = Pattern.compile("$");
    Matcher newMatcherValue = specialCharacters.matcher(newValue) ;
    newValue = newMatcherValue.replaceAll("\\\\$") ;
}
```

This runs into an error. Is there any elegant way of replacing my second string `"abc$ def$"` with `"abc\\\\$ def\\\\$"` so as to use the `replacefirst()` API successfully?

Comment: You can do `Pattern.compile(text, Pattern.LITERAL);`

Comment: Using Pattern and Matcher with Pattern.compile(newValue, Pattern.LITERAL); will result in the string reduced to "$"..that will not help.. :(

Comment: Try to use  Pattern specialCharacters = Pattern.compile("\\$");

Comment: No Effect on the input string with Pattern.compile("\\$") Sample Code :  public static String escapeDollarSymbol(String newValue){
  if(newValue.contains("$")){
   Pattern specialCharacters = Pattern.compile("\\$");
   Matcher newMatcherValue = specialCharacters.matcher(newValue) ;
   newValue = newMatcherValue.replaceAll("\\$") ; 
  }
  System.out.println(newValue);
  return newValue;
 }

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a bit more? What exactly you want to do?

Comment: I have a string "abc$ def$ ", i am trying to replace this string with "abc\\$ def\\$". The string may not always be abc or def, IN general any string containing $ i am trying to replace $ symbol with \\$

Comment: If your string is not long then you can try below code:                     String[]  splits = newValue.split("\\$"); StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(); for(int i=0; i < splits.length; i++){   buff.append(splits[i]).append("\\\\$");}

Answer (score 0):

Look at `Pattern.quote()` to quote a regex and `Matcher.quoteReplacement()` to quote a replacement string.

That said, does this do what you want it to?

```
System.out.println("abc def".replaceAll("([\\w]+)\\b", "$1\\$"));
```

This prints out `abc$ def$`

Comment: Thanks for your reply..My Original String contains $.that is "abc $ def$" and my output needs to be "abc\\$ def\\$"..

Answer (score 0):

You can use replaceAll just in one step:

```
String newValueScaped = newValue.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\$")
```

*$* has a special mining in regex, so you need to scape it. It's used to match the end of the data.